# jQuery doesnt work on Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery

I have jQuery script version ("1.12.4") :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var strUserTimeZone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
    $(".timezone").val(strUserTimeZone);
```

Which is actually being ignored by Internet Explorer 10 . It works  in Firefox/Chome/Opera and Microsoft Edge.
Can anyone help me to understand where is my error ?

Comment: Which jQuery version are you using? You need jQuery 1.x for IE8 and older, see http://jquery.com/browser-support/

Comment: Your information is way too vague. What jQuery version? What IE version? Is it really being ignored, or just crashing?

Comment: I use  ( "1.12.4" )

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is due to the use of `Intl.DateTimeFormat()`. It is unsupported in <IE11. You would need to dissect the ISO date string manually to achieve what you require reliably in legacy browsers.

See [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat#Browser_compatibility) for more information.